# How do I get items hidden with JQuery to return using dropdown menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to use a dropdown to filter by category using JQuery. I'm new to this, so any help is appreciated!

When you select "Category 1 + Things," it should hide all the other categories and their respective Things. Same with the other dropdown options. The problem comes when switching between dropdown items after already having chosen one. I can't get hidden items to re-appear. Thanks for the help!

```
<select id="categoryFilter">
  <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Filter by...</option>
  <option value="0">Show All Categories + Things</option>
  <option value="1">Category 1 + Things</option>
  <option value="2">Category 2 + Things</option>
</select>

<h1 class="category-1">Category 1</h1>
    <div class="thing thing-category-1">
        <span>thing 1</span>
    </div>
    <div class="thing thing-category-1">
        <span>thing 2</span>
    </div>
    <div class="thing thing-category-1">
        <span>thing 3</span>
    </div>
<h1 class="category-2">Category 2</h1>
    <div class="thing thing-category-2">
        <span>thing 4</span>
    </div>
    <div class="thing thing-category-2">
        <span>thing 5</span>
    </div>
    <div class="thing thing-category-2">
        <span>thing 6</span>
    </div>
```

Here's the javaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#categoryFilter').on('change', function() {
      if($(this).val() == '1') {
          $('h1:not(.category-1)').hide();
          $('.thing:not(.thing-category-1)').hide();
      } 
      if($(this).val() == '2') {
          $('h1:not(.category-2)').hide();
          $('.thing:not(.thing-category-2)').hide();
      }
      if($(this).val() == '0') {
          location.reload();
      }
  });
});
```

Demo:
http://codepen.io/drews1949/pen/oBbGma?editors=1010

I'm new to front-end, so thanks for any help!

Comment: Show them all (`$('h1, .thing').show()`) at the top of your change handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With jQuery you can use CSS substring selectors on HTML attributes. They're quite useful, and it won't require you to change your naming convention or any HTML.

**edit:** Ultimately, if you're writing your own HTML this is sort of redundant, and a better way would be to wrap your categorical items in their own parent element, rather than naming everything separately.

#### Here is an example

```js
// Always cache DOM queries

// returns all elements with class ending in "category-1"
var $opt1 = $('[class$="category-1"]')

// returns all elements with class ending in "category-2"
var $opt2 = $('[class$="category-2"]')

var $selector = $('#categoryFilter')

window.onload = init()

function init(){
  
  $selector.on('change',function(){

    if($selector.val()==0){$opt2.show();$opt1.show()}
    if($selector.val()==1){$opt1.show();$opt2.hide()}
    if($selector.val()==2){$opt2.show();$opt1.hide()}

  })
    
}
```

```html
<select id="categoryFilter">
  <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Filter by...</option>
  <option value="0">Show All Categories + Things</option>
  <option value="1">Category 1 + Things</option>
  <option value="2">Category 2 + Things</option>
</select>

<h1 class="category-1">Category 1</h1>
    <div class="thing thing-category-1">
        <span>thing 1</span>
    </div>
    <div class="thing thing-category-1">
        <span>thing 2</span>
    </div>
    <div class="thing thing-category-1">
        <span>thing 3</span>
    </div>
<h1 class="category-2">Category 2</h1>
    <div class="thing thing-category-2">
        <span>thing 4</span>
    </div>
    <div class="thing thing-category-2">
        <span>thing 5</span>
    </div>
    <div class="thing thing-category-2">
        <span>thing 6</span>
    </div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Slight change to the naming - simply hide all elements inititially and then on the select .show() selected options. Also as @JoshuaT suggested - bettter to wrap all elements in a parent container with a single class name and remove the individual classes - unless of course you want to do diferent things with the .thin classes etc. The following is the edited simpler version.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#categoryFilter').on('change', function() {
    var sel = $(this).val();
      $('.category').hide();
      $('.thing').hide();
      $('.category'+ sel).show();
      $('.thing' + sel).show();
  });
});
```

```css
.category{display:none}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="categoryFilter">
  <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Filter by...</option>
  <option value="">Show All Categories + Things</option>
  <option value="1">Category 1 + Things</option>
  <option value="2">Category 2 + Things</option>
</select>

<div class="category category1">
  <h1>Category 1</h1>
    <div>
        <span>thing 1</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span>thing 2</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span>thing 3</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class= "category category2">
  <h1>Category 2</h1>
    <div>
        <span>thing 4</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span>thing 5</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span>thing 6</span>
    </div>
</div>
```